# Correct form of possessive for surname "Woods"

Tags: possessives

The golfer Tiger Woods's clubs...  -or-

The golfer Tiger Woods' clubs...

The last name Woods is not biblical, etc.  It is singular when it refers to the person, Tiger Woods.  It is plural when it is the word, "woods".

I have, literally, seen it both ways, online and in newsprint, and ask which is correct. (I'll go out on a limb and say that the first example seems right to me, and yet it is the second example that I see more often in print and online)

Thank you very much for any education you can provide me on this matter.  Sincerely, Sven

Comment: Thank you for the link, tchrist.  From the link you gave me (and Strunk&White): "Examples they give include Kansas’s, Ross’s land, and Jones’s reputation. Exceptions include Jesus’  and Moses’." So, I think Biblical does have something to do with choosing possessives (but Woods is not a Biblical name, for sure).  I can see saying this Woods clubs or Woodss clubs, so my ear is an unreliable source (as is the ear of the various journalists that use it both ways).  Which way do you say it, and thus, which do you think is correct, please?

Comment: Read the answer, not the question. There is nothing whatsoever Biblical about any rule. The only rule is to write down what people say, and there is no exception to this: speech is primary. Most people would say *Tiger Woods’s clubs* with an extra syllable, so you have to write what they say.  Pay no attention to the media: they are notoriously under- or mis-educated in matters orthographical and philological.

Comment: 'Boss', 'princess' and 'Woods' are **singular** nouns. [BBC WS](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv57.shtml) advises ... if the singular noun ends in 's' as in your example, ... you can either just add an apostrophe (') or apostrophe _s_ ('s):
'All of Dickens' novels have now been adapted for television.'
'All of Dickens's novels have now been adapted for television.' I'm sure tchrist would endorse this in spite of its source; he goes further, giving a sensible reason for choosing a particular version, based on pronunciation.

Answer (score 0):

Although *Woods'* is often used by writers who should know better, it is a mistake:

[**Strunk and White - Form the possessive singular of nouns with 's.**](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk.html)

> Form the possessive singular of nouns with 's.
>
> Follow this rule whatever the final consonant. Thus write,
>
> Charles's friend
>       Burns's poems
>       the witch's malice
>
> This is the usage of the United States Government Printing Office and of the Oxford University Press.

When used as proper names, *Woods* or *Burns* are **singular** forms.

For further reference, see [**Apostrophes**](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp); [**Lesson Five - Possessive nouns**](http://literacy.kent.edu/Midwest/Materials/ndakota/spelling/lesson5.html);

Comment: Why should one accept S & W's recommendations over those of other style gurus (and possibly prevailing usage)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth : Because they make sense: A proper name is not plural. Besides, they bring authoritative references, and I have added some more sources. Do you have a source which contradicts them? **Oxford University Press** is not sufficient? You are free to bring another source and answer the question differently, if you disagree.

Comment: They don't make as much sense as tchrist's 'general rule' as he calls it in the previous answer. CMOS says 'Either is correct, though we prefer the latter.' Associated Press (AP) and Modern Language Association (MLA) require '. The Guardian-Observer SG seems to make more sense: 'The possessive in words and names ending in S normally takes an apostrophe followed by a second S (Jones's, James's), but be guided by pronunciation and use the [bare] apostrophe where it helps: Mephistopheles', Waters', Hedges', not Mephistopheles's, Waters's, Hedges's.' The apostrophe is a servant, not a sacred cow.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - _be guided by pronunciation_ - I think it depends on the word - I hear the argument for  `Mephistopheles`. Regardless `Woods'`just sounds wrong - you don't hear the possessive.